# Tags synonyms/merge requests

Tags: support, synonym-request

Some typo and naming divergence...

- [notification](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notification) and [notifications](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notifications)
- [hangouts](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hangouts) and [google-plus-hangouts](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-plus-hangouts)
- [system-partition](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-partition) and [partition](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merged the first two. Not sure about [system-partition](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-partition) and [partition](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partition) as the are not semantically equal. I'd like to hear a few more voices on that.

Comment: Full ack from me: Merge the first two. On a first look, `system-partition` is a *subset* of `partition`. Checking its question (yes, singular), I'd even count it "obsolete"; I'd say simply re-tag the one question.